# Trying to insert data into database but this error appears: KeyError: 'identifier' (Python)

Tags: python, csv, python-requests

What i want to accomplish is to grab data from API-endpoint and store it as CSV. Then import CSV file into SQLite database. I can fetch the data from API just fine and output in CSV file. But to store the data from CSV file into SQLite is the problem. I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "info.py", line 46, in <module>
     i['col1'], i['col2'], i['col3'], 
     i['col4'], i['col5']) for i in dr]
   File "info.py", line 46, in <listcomp>
     i['col1'], i['col2'], i['col3'], 
     i['col4'], i['col5']) for i in dr]
KeyError: 'col1'
```

I wonder why this error appears?

If there any other solutions I'm gladly and open for help. The goal is to store the data from CSV file into SQLite database.

Here is what i have so far:

```
import requests
import csv
import sqlite3


con = sqlite3.connect("business.db")
cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS firms')

cur.execute(
 "CREATE TABLE firms (col1 PRIMARY KEY, col2 TEXT, col3 TEXT, "
 "col4 TEXT, col5 TEXT,...);"
 )

r = requests.get('http://url/url/url')

outfile = open(r"C:\Users\...\test.csv", "w")
outfile.write(r.text)


with open(r'C:\Users\...\...\test.csv', 'r') as fin: 
dr = csv.DictReader(fin) 
to_db = [(i['col1'], i['col2'], i['col3'], i['col4'], i['col5'], ...) for i in dr]


cur.executemany("INSERT INTO firms (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5,  "...) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, "
                "...);", to_db)
con.commit()
con.close()
```

---

Output from this command (`print(next(dr))`):

```
OrderedDict([('col1;"col2";"col3";"col4";"col5";"..."', 'value1;"value2";                                                     
"value3";"value4";"value5";"..."')])
```

Comment: In the array of dicts `dr` you don't have identifier key. To be precise may be your csv doesn't have identifier column

Comment: @ArpitSolanki identifier  column is there..but it does not have "identifier"..it outputs without -> " " only like this..  identifier

Comment: after `dr = csv.DictReader(fin)`, if you insert a line `print(next(dr))`, what does it print out?

Comment: also, if you just read the file, what are the contents of the first line?

Comment: @e.s. I will output it above since the row is to long xD

Comment: @e.s. Sorry for the formating..not so easy to do it here xD

Comment: try `dr = csv.DictReader(fin, delimiter=';')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168942/discussion-between-e-s-and-niknak).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the delimiter in your csv file is `';'` instead of the default `','`.  So it reads the entire row as one entry, since it's trying to split it at the non-existent commas.

use `dr = csv.DictReader(fin, delimiter=';')`

Comment: I would like to give you a big hug and kiss =D no homo ofc xD 
If you have time, can we talk in a private chat room? Is some other questions i would like to ask you. Again, no homo hehe xD